# Excel merge columns problem

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns that a client has sent me... unfortunately some contents are on another column. I want to make it so that all the data lines up in just column... how do I make this happen?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

On a COPY of your workbook, I'd set up a formula in column G that concatenates the values in columns E and F, trims any excess "white" space or blank space (just in case), then copy and 'paste special /values' the results in G back into E.

Your formula in cell G1 might be =TRIM(CONCATENATE(E1,F1))

Or, use the ampersand (&) operator to concatenate:   = TRIM(E1 & F1).

I personally prefer the "&" operator.

Comment: Exactly how I'd do it too. No Excel here, but I seem to remember there's also a Paste Special option that can add up, multiply, etcetera while pasting. Maybe there's also an option to concatenate on paste?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another choice, though it won't work if there is any other data to the right of this section of your spreadsheet.

1. Highlight the whole area under question in this case E1:E3
2. Press Ctrl + G
3. Click Special
4. Select Blanks; Click OK.
5. Right-click on a selected cell and click Delete... and Shift Cells Left.